# How do you bar plot the nlargest of aggregated groupby data?

Tags: pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby, bar-chart, seaborn

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere, but I'm not great with pandas and need someone to break it down for me.

I have this function:

```
def process_data(data):
    data = data[data['Bucket Number'] == 25.0].groupby(['Activity Month', 'Agent Sign']).agg({'Total Ping Current Forecast': [np.sum]})
    return data
```

**EDIT: Fixed Sample**

That produces this output:

```
                          Total Ping Current Forecast
                                                  sum
Activity Month Agent Sign                            
202001         CRCDIF                        618485.0
               CRCTLD                      47746137.0
               DFW1DF                      16220228.0
               HDQ9LO                         19995.0
               HDQBDE                         10739.0
...                                               ...
202007         HDQRPT                             0.0
               HDQZED                             0.0
               MSCUHD                             0.0
               RDUSMD                         56732.0
               {Various}                  245079251.0
```

**How would I make a bar plot where the X-axis is the `Activity Month`, the Y-axis is the sum, and for each tick is the two largest `Agent Sign` bars?**

So for example the tick at `202001` would have two bars, one for `Agent Sign` CRCTLD and one for DFW1DF.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try extracting the rows with `groupby().cumcount` (also possible with `nlargest`), then plot with  `sns.barplot()`:

```
processed = process_data(data)

sns.barplot(data=processed.sort_values('sum',ascending=False)
                     .assign(rank=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
                     .reset_index()
                     .loc[lambda x: x['rank']<=1],
            x='Activity Month',y='sum', hue='rank'     
           )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I got an error that says `Dataframe object has no attribute to_frame`. When I took out to_frame(), I got a KeyError for 'sum'.

Comment: Just drop `to_frame` since you already have a dataframe. See updated answer.

Comment: I did. I got a key error for `sum`. I didn't have a column named sum, that's just what returned when I called `.agg({'Total Ping Current Forecast' :[np.sum]})`

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention tat `data` here is the output of `process_data(data)`.

Comment: Yes, it is the output I'm using. But I'm getting `in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'sum'` since I don't think `sum` is actually a Series in the dataframe, right?

Comment: If you look at my sample, you can see that `Activity Month` and `Agent Sign` are blue because they are actual columns, whereas `sum` is not blue since it is just the result of the aggregate function.

Comment: Would changing `sum` to `Total Ping Current Forecast` work?  I think that might be the correct way but I'm getting a `ValueError: The column label 'Total Ping Current Forecast' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.` error and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I made an error in the sample. I've fixed it. The column name for sum is actually `Total Ping Current Forecast`. Could you take a look now, please?

Comment: When I try `data.sort_values(('Total Ping Current Forecast'), ascending=False)` I get a `ValueError: The column label 'Total Ping Current Forecast' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.`